# Java misinterpreting apostrophes when parsing input

Tags: java, json, parsing

So I am trying to use the wikipedia api to read the first paragraph of a given wikipedia page.  Unfortunately, I wikipedia uses a weird system to deal with special characters, (http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Data_formats#JSON_parameters) and I was unable to parse the default [response](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&exintro=&titles=lorde) without getting the characters with escape sequences.  Obviously the best solution would be to interpret these directly in java, but I'm not sure there is a way to do that, so I force a utf8 [response](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&utf8&exintro=&titles=lorde).  This approach looks like it should work, but when I pass it through my parsing code, it returns:

```
Ella Marija Lani Yelich-O'Connor (born 7 November 1996).....named among Time?'?s most influential teenagers in the world, and in the following year, she made her way into Forbes?'?s "30 Under 30" list.
```

Notice that some apostrophes are kept and some aren't.  I think that the misinterpreted characters are the result of parsing of previous parsing (I want the plaintext, so I parse the html tags out).  Here is my parsing code, its a bit messy but it almost works:

```
public static String getWikiParagraph (String url){
    try {
        //System.out.println(url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
        URL apiURL = new URL("http://www.en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&utf8&exintro=&titles="+url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(apiURL.openStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        String read = br.readLine();
        while(read != null) {
            sb.append(read);
            read =br.readLine();
        }
        String s = sb.toString();
        s = Arrays.toString(getTagValues(s).toArray());
        s=s.replace("<i>","");
        s=s.replace("</i>","");
        s=s.replace("?'?","'"); //makes no difference in output
        s=s.replace("u200a","");
        s=s.replace("<b>","");
        s=s.replace("</b>","");
        s=s.replace("\\","");
        s=s.substring(1, s.length() -1);
        return s;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Error fetching data from url");
    }
    return null;
}

private static List<String> getTagValues(final String str) {
    final Pattern TAG_REGEX = Pattern.compile("<p>(.+?)</p>");
    final List<String> tagValues = new ArrayList<String>();
    final Matcher matcher = TAG_REGEX.matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        tagValues.add(matcher.group(1));
    }
    return tagValues;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use a JSON parser?!

Comment: regardless, I would still have to parse out the html tags, which is where I think my problem is

Comment: I suspect the ?'s aren't actual question marks, but they're characters your terminal is unable to display (so it displayed question marks instead).

Comment: Not the case - I put these strings in a database, and they are still displayed the same as in the terminal.  It may be a larger problem with string formatting/corruption, but I am specifying utf8 so it should have no trouble.

Comment: "they are still displayed the same as in the terminal" - are you displaying the database contents in a terminal?

Comment: No, I am looking at them through phpMyAdmin in my browser

Answer (score 0):

Use a JSON parser and run the results you want to cleanup through something like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/). Sure, you could write your own brittle HTML parser, but this is a bit of a fool's errand. HTML is subtle, and quick to anger. Spend your time building your logic and let the utility classes do the grungy stuff.

And, yes. The comments are correct. This JSON has Unicode sequences in it, at least when I look at that URL, which will not render correctly in most terminals.

EDIT

The JSON format is (apparently) subject to change. I got cleaner output by specifying "&continue=" in the URL to go back to an older continuation format. You should probably find out what these continuation format changes mean for you.